# how to multiply integers from a random list

Tags: python

I have already imported random and made the list but I have to multiply all the integers from that list and print the outcome.
But with this setup, I just get a whole bunch of numbers repeated again and again. I have tried other setups but none of them seem to work for this specific problem.
It should be if (i) stands for numbers in list i*i*i*i*i*i... and so on and then just print the outcome???

```
listi=[]

    for i in range(50):
        listi.append(random.randint(5,70))
        teljari=1
        listi=listi
        for x in listi:
            teljari*=x
            print(teljari)
```

Comment: what this line `listi.append(random.randint(5,70))` for? why `(5,70)` ?

Comment: You are calculating a product each time a new random number is added. And you are printing a sub-product each time it is multiplied. This is why you see a lot of numbers. Besides, the line `listi = listi` does nothing useful.

Comment: listi.append(random.randint(5,70))  it´s there so the 50 numbers in range are just random numbers between 5 and 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kept printing all the numbers, as you had your print function in the for loop, so each time the loop reached the next integer, it printed the product.

```
from random import randint
listi = []

for x in range(50):
    listi.append(randint(5,70))

teljari = 1

for i in listi:
    teljari *= i

print(teljari)
```

I think this should work as intended.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I´m learning python so this for me is a great help

Answer (score 4):

More pythonesque would be

```
random_numbers = random.sample(range(5, 70), 50)
teljari = 1
other_list = [i * teljari for i in random_numbers]
```

Thus you get all the random numbers with one command and then you can multiply with whichever process you want.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you:-

```
import random

uniqueRandomNumberList = random.sample(range(5,70), 50)

reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,uniqueRandomNumberList)
```

Comment: I would just add that in python 3, reduce has to be imported from `functools`.